# Set and check for login cookies?

Tags: php, session, cookies

I'm a bit a of newbie with PHP cookies and sessions.

I'm using the PHPauth project and one of their instructions has got me confused. From their wiki (here: https://github.com/PHPAuth/PHPAuth/wiki/Class-Methods), there is note on the login function:

> Note: You need to take the returned session hash and create the
>   session cookie, the method does not do this for you.

I'm not asking this question for the PHPauth project, but for all authentications as this is what I don't understand. Specifically, what keeps the session secure? And do I need to do something with hash that I'm given as per the array?

```
Array (
    [error] => 
    [message] => You are now logged in. 
    [hash] => 2ec4b290cedd651cf1c20635a887dd7f7042dc54 
    [expire] => 0 
)
```

I mean, I could set a cookie, but then what? How do I know if that cookie is valid for this particular log on?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "What keeps the session secure?" but yes, you need to store the login hash in a cookie. You can use `checkSession` to check if the cookie IS valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the native session mechanism in PHP, calling `session_start()` automatically sends the HTTP answer necessary to create a cookie containing the hash of the session ID to the client (that is the reason why no output should be placed before calling `session_start()` btw.). By default this cookie name is "PHPSESSID", so PHP first of all checks if there is a cookie with a hash with that value when you request a page and if yes, it continues your session again.

For sure, you can also rename the default session cookie name, etc.
You should have a look at the PHP session options here: http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php

In short: Usually it's not necessary to save the session hash anywhere (and you also **should not** for security reasons, unless you have a valid reason for it) and PHP handles it automatically.

Comment: Thanks. My problem was solved with your info. In my case, I had to start the session and set a cookie of the name that the code checks for authentication.